# Add Entity Selection Input to Suitelet?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

How can I add a 'Customer' input field to my suitelet? See the below image for the input field I am referring to.

[image]

I know how to add a standard field, such as a text field to a form:

```
form.addField({
    id: 'my_select',
    type : ui.FieldType.SELECT,  // Theres no entity fieldtype?
    label : 'Select box'
});
```

I hope there is such a thing in SuiteScript. If not, any suggestions of an alternative? My suitelet pretty much does 3 things; it creates a customer (if they don't exist - thus the need for the customer input above), creates a sales order and then creates an Inventory Adjustment. The catalyst is the customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the source parameter and point it to 'customer'.  Something like this:

```
form.addField({
  id: 'custpage_customer',
  type: ui.FieldType.SELECT,
  label: 'Customer',
  source: 'customer'
});
```